# How to execute a mapping on <F7> key from a script?

Tags: vimscript, key-bindings

I have the following mapping in my project:

```
nnoremap <F7> :execute '!gtags'<cr> :cscope kill -1<cr> :cscope add CTAGS<cr>
```

Under certain conditions I want to be able to execute this mapping from a script, i.e.

```
if (mycondition)
  execute 'normal <F7>'
endif
```

The code above didn't work.

Does anybody know if it is possible to do something like that?

Comment: In my opinion this would be better off in a command. `command! RerfreshTags !gtags<bar>cscope kill -1<bar>cscope add GTAGS`. Then map `<f7>` to this command and execute your the command directly in your function.

Comment: Could <ESC><F7> work?

Comment: @PeterRincker I agree, this would be better off as a command. I was just not familiar with he syntax of how to define one. Well, I will have to learn it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You have to insert the escape code corresponding to <kbd>F7</kbd>.

To do so in insert mode on my system, I used <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd>. It inserted `^[[18~` and the script worked.

Comment: Or use double quotes and escape. e.g. `execute "normal \<f7>"`. Or even better yet just use `:normal`. e.g. `normal <f7>`

Comment: @PeterRincker The double quoting doesnt seems to work on my system Debian + xterm + tmux + vim 7.4... maybe it comes from my terminal emulator?

Comment: @statox For some reason your suggestion didn't work. When I executed Ctrl-F7 it inserted `<F7>`

Comment: @PeterRincker It worked on my system. What is the difference between single quotes and double quotes?

Comment: @flashburn In your comment you wrote you used `Ctrl + F7` but I suggested to use `Ctrl + v + F7` I'm not sure if you just forgot it in your comment or if you didn't see it in my answer?

Comment: @statox Sorry this was a typo. It should be `Ctrl + v + F7`

Comment: @flashburn Well I don't know how to explain that... Maybe a Vim expert of the site will know what's happening. Sorry if that didn't help.

Comment: @statox No worries. Thanks for the effort.

Comment: To understand the double quote escaping rules I suggest reading `:h expr-quote`. An except: `\<xxx>` Special key named "`xxx`".  e.g. `"\<C-W>"` for CTRL-W.

Comment: @statox The technique should work across all terminal emulators. I did however make a mistake. You can not do just `normal <f7>`. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: @PeterRincker: It does work with `normal <f7>` on my system, thanks. Also maybe you should make it an answer since mine didn't satisfied OP.

Comment: Single quotes don't do any expansion, double quotes do. See `:h expr-string` vs the immediately following `:h literal-string`. Most notably, backslashes don't mean anything special in single-quote strings. But then this means that all of the escapes don't do anything either; use double quotes to get magic things to happen. (Single quoted strings are great for regexes, for example.)

Comment: @flashburn If you got a differently colored `<F7>` in your buffer then you probably did it right. Ctrl-V, release both keys, *then* F7.

Answer (score 2):

A workaround may be put the code in a function:

```
function! CallF7()
    execute '!gtags'<cr> :cscope kill -1<cr> :cscope add CTAGS<cr>
endfunction
nnoremap <F7> :call CallF7()
```

So you can use:

```
if (mycondition)
  call CallF7()
endif
```